# In Wix , How to get substring of registry key value in a property?

Tags: c#, excel, wix, registry

In my application deployment we are verifying which version of excel client is installed in a machine.

Some times if multiple versions are installed then we are trying to get latest version of excel then install our add-in .

we need to get the latest version number of Excel to search in registry.

Following registry

> "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Excel.Application\CurVer"

which is giving value for Excel 2016 as

> Excel.Application.16

How to get the number 16 alone from this into property? We have to get this because we have to install our Msi if excel 2010 or above is installed.

Comment: Why do you need a version of Excel to install? The target registry key is version-independent. I mean, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins

Comment: Did you ever get it to work? I need the same thing for Word... @Nikolay I need to enable the disabled items during the installation... and that is in version specific key in registry.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reading the registry and then playing with the string value, you can do a component search for the excel component ID which is a more robust technique:

Please find below the component ID for other Excel versions.

1. Excel 2007 Component ID: {0638C49D-BB8B-4CD1-B191-052E8F325736}
2. Excel 2010 x86: {538F6C89-2AD5-4006-8154-C6670774E980}
3. Excel 2010 x64: {8B1BF0B4-A1CA-4656-AA46-D11C50BC55A4}
4. Excel 2013 x86: {C8A65ABE-3270-4FD7-B854-50C8082C8F39}
5. Excel 2013 x64: {E3BD1151-B9CA-4D45-A77E-51A6E0ED322A}
6. Excel 2016 x86: {C845E028-E091-442E-8202-21F596C559A0}
7. Excel 2016 x64: {C4ACE6DB-AA99-401F-8BE6-8784BD09F003}

Hope that helps!

EDIT: You can do something like this:

```
    <Property Id="EXCEL2016Search">
              <ComponentSearch Id="DetectExcel1" Guid="{C4ACE6DB-AA99-401F-8BE6-8784BD09F003}" Type="file"/>
            </Property>

<Property Id="EXCEL2013Search">
          <ComponentSearch Id="DetectExcel2" Guid="{E3BD1151-B9CA-4D45-A77E-51A6E0ED322A}" Type="file"/>
        </Property>

<Property Id="EXCEL2010Search">
          <ComponentSearch Id="DetectExcel3" Guid="{8B1BF0B4-A1CA-4656-AA46-D11C50BC55A4}" Type="file"/>
        </Property>

    <Property Id="EXCELVersion" Value="0" />

    <SetProperty Id="EXCELVersion" After="DetectExcel3" Value="1" Sequence="first" >
      <[CDATA[EXCEL2016Search OR EXCEL2013Search OR EXCEL2010Search]]>
    </SetProperty>
```

If the value of the property "EXCELVersion" is 1 then Excel 2010 or above is installed. If it is 0, then excel 2010 or above is not installed.

Comment: but this check will be like hard coded check for particular version. What we required is any version of excel on or above 2010 is installed.

Comment: Updated the answer, check it out.

Comment: Sam - please mark it as the answer, if this answered your question.

Comment: Still it is bound till Excel 2016. I tried to get Version Number alone from that registry as it will be used in office registry key. If Office 2018 is released with Excel.application.18 that registry will be Office\18.0 . If i get the version then i can achieve this. So it is not answering the question exactly so i just upvoted only