# Split string in WIX Bootstrapper

Tags: string, wix

I have a property named "Version" in my bootstrapper project. It contains the version as a dot separated value (1.2.3). I only need to get the last numeric value.

How to perform a string operation within this WIX bootstrapper ? Is it possible or are there any other alternatives ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Expressions.

https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/com-expression-syntax-miscellanea/expression-syntax/

For your specific condition, ENDS WITH Expression should work ( >> )

Comment: Can you please provide with some example code in this ?

Comment: What exactly do you need to do with the extracted value. do you want to store it in a separate variable or just check its existence and use it in a condition ?

Comment: I need to put it in a property and use it to check another value in the registry

Comment: I believe you should do the opposite. Get the registry search done. Put that value in a variable/property and then compare it to the version using the expressions.

Comment: This is what i do *    <util:RegistrySearch Id="ServiceSearch" 
                         Root="HKCR" 
                         Key="Outlook.Application\CurVer" 
                         Format="raw"
                         Variable="CurrentVersion"/> *
This produces a value as *Applicaiton.Outlook.15* 

I need to extract 15.

Comment: I believe you are trying to get the Outlook version. This should help you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37832411/in-wix-how-to-get-substring-of-registry-key-value-in-a-property

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122802/discussion-between-nilaksha-perera-and-ashutosh-vyas).